# Telerik TeamPulse main menu and context menu, how?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, rad-controls

I like the Telerik's Main and context aware menu in TeamPulse.

I am targeting Silverlight4 here using SL 4 Rad Controls.

Is there a sample project where this is implemented (using the Office Dark theme) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [RadContextMenu](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radcontextmenu-features-working-with-radcontext-menu.html)

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
     <telerik:RadContextMenu telerik:StyleManager.Theme="{StaticResource OfficeDarkTheme}">
          <telerik:RadMenuItem Click="RadMenuItem_Click" Header="My Menu Item"/>
     </telerik:RadContextMenu>
</telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
```

`ContextMenu` is an attached property and can be attached to any `FrameworkElement`